# Getting TS2739 error in function for fetching data in Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

I created this function for fetching objects from my dummy data and setting it to a variable.

```
setData(key: string) {
    let dataChunk: ProductIndex = PRODUCTDATA.filter(a=>{a.productId == key;});
    this.ProductData = dataChunk;
}
```

I'm getting the TS2739 error at line 15,13 which is right where `dataChunk` begins stating that each property in the `ProductIndex` type is missing from the type `ProductIndex[]` which is the type of `PRODUCTDATA`.

My data is saved like this

```
export const PRODUCTDATA: ProductIndex[] = [
    {
        productId: 'divider_01',
        title: 'Divider 01',
        description: 'A brief description for Divider 01',
        sizes: [...],
        instructionKey: 'divider_01_instruction_key'
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

The `ProductIndex` interface looks like this

```
export interface ProductIdCore           { productId   : string; }    
export interface TitleCore               { title       : string; }
export interface ShortDescriptionCore    { description : string; }

export interface ProductIndex extends ProductIdCore, TitleCore, ShortDescriptionCore{
    sizes: ProductIndexItem[];
    instructionKey: string;
}
```

I'm using Angular 8 with TypeScript 3.4.0. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you *filter* a list, you *still have a list*.

So you don't have :

```
let dataChunk: ProductIndex = PRODUCTDATA.filter(a=> a.productId === key);
```

but

```
let dataChunk: ProductIndex[] = PRODUCTDATA.filter(a=> a.productId === key);
```

If you want to **FIND** the item, then use `find`, it returns the first element that satisfies your condition :

```
let dataChunk: ProductIndex = PRODUCTDATA.find(a=> a.productId === key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
setData(key: string){
    let dataChunk: ProductIndex = PRODUCTDATA.filter(a=>a.productId == key);
    this.ProductData = dataChunk;
}
```

You had `{a.productId == key;}` which is wrong.

If you want to use curly braces do the following:

```
....PRODUCTDATA.filter(a=>{ return a.productId == key;});
```

Comment: I had already accepted the other answer but I gave this a + because I did indeed notice I forgot the `return` in my own code.